# searching for c++ code parser to see all signatures

Tags: c++, parsing, header-files, method-signature

I'm looking for a c++ parser which is able to extract all the functions and methods with its signatures. Is there something like this?

I had a look at gccxml there I have the problem, that it is not able to use namespaces and its not fine when only a header file is present.

Comment: +1, by the way for last 2 year as a part of my side project, I have written one parser, which extracts method/function signature from `class, namespace, internal class` etc. I want to make it commercialize sometime.

Comment: @iammilind: i focus on making money materialize. No definite results yet

Comment: @sehe, means ? you have also written something like that ? Well what I am talking about is not just a parser. It's a project for automatic garbage collector which includes this part of extracting signatures of pointers, classes, namespaces, function/methods and so on.

Comment: What are you talking about? Of course gccxml does handle and understand namespaces and what do you mean with "not fine when only a header file is present"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Clang compiler obviously has the functionality to do this, if I remember correctly there's even an API to access the code tree generated by the parser.

Comment: There is. CLang generates an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) of the code and provides a `ConsumerAST` base class for visiting it.

Comment: I rather thought of libclang (http://llvm.org/devmtg/2010-11/Gregor-libclang.pdf) but that ought to work too

Comment: libclang is the C-API. If you have access to C++, you'll have more complete information directly interfacing as some features take time to be ported to the C-API. For simple things as declarations, it should be perfectly suitable, though perhaps not as suitable since C-code does take some amount of effort.

Answer (score 4):

Most obvious options:

1. ctags
2. cscope

Just a sample of the GCC man page:

```
-fdump-noaddr -fdump-unnumbered -fdump-translation-unit[-n] -fdump-class-hierarchy[-n] -fdump-ipa-all -fdump-ipa-cgraph -fdump-ipa-inline
           -fdump-statistics -fdump-tree-all -fdump-tree-original[-n] -fdump-tree-optimized[-n] -fdump-tree-cfg -fdump-tree-vcg -fdump-tree-alias -fdump-tree-ch -fdump-tree-ssa[-n] -fdump-tree-pre[-n] -fdump-tree-ccp[-n] -fdump-tree-dce[-n]
           -fdump-tree-gimple[-raw] -fdump-tree-mudflap[-n] -fdump-tree-dom[-n] -fdump-tree-dse[-n] -fdump-tree-phiopt[-n] -fdump-tree-forwprop[-n] -fdump-tree-copyrename[-n] -fdump-tree-nrv -fdump-tree-vect -fdump-tree-sink -fdump-tree-sra[-n]
           -fdump-tree-fre[-n] -fdump-tree-vrp
```

Also there is a [gccxml backend](http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-dump` option of the [abi-compliance-checker](http://lvc.github.io/abi-compliance-checker/) tool to parse signatures of functions and methods from your header file(s):

```
abi-compliance-checker -lib NAME -dump DESC.xml -headers-only -stdout > api.dump
```

XML-descriptor (`DESC.xml`) is the following:

```
<version>
    VERSION
</version>

<headers>
    /path(s)/to/headers/
</headers>
```

The tool works as following:

1. Call `GCC` with `-fdump-translation-unit` and a set of automagically generated `-I...` options on the headers specified in the input XML-descriptor;
2. Parse the AST dump generated by the `GCC`;
3. Generate function signatures and type definitions in the [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Data-Dumper-2.131/Dumper.pm) or XML format (if additional `-xml` option is provided).

The sample signature of `int BZ2_bzRead ( int *bzerror, BZFILE *b, void *buf, int len )` function from `bzlib.h` header looks like:

```
'228' => {
   'Header' => 'bzlib.h',
   'Line' => '160',
   'Param' => {
                '0' => {
                         'algn' => '4',
                         'name' => 'bzerror',
                         'type' => '30'
                       },
                '1' => {
                         'algn' => '4',
                         'name' => 'b',
                         'type' => '16'
                       },
                '2' => {
                         'algn' => '4',
                         'name' => 'buf',
                         'type' => '68'
                       },
                '3' => {
                         'algn' => '4',
                         'name' => 'len',
                         'type' => '41'
                       }
              },
   'Return' => '41',
   'ShortName' => 'BZ2_bzRead'
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try compiling your code with the `save-temps` flag set on gcc, this makes gcc output the files with macro unfolding and full signatures. these are the .ii files.

Comment: this makes nearly the same output as in the header file, but i need a parsed output that is easy to extract for other programms